# How do I Mirror Various Cells between Sheets in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a worksheet that needs single cells to mirror single cells on another sheet and vice versa if it gets changed. I found this code on superuser:

For Sheet 1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target as Range)
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B7").Value = Target.Value
End Sub
```

For Sheet 2:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target as Range)
If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value <> Target.Value Then
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value = Target.Value 
End if
End Sub
```

But I cannot get it to work. I get an error that says:

> Run-time error '9':
>
> Subscript out of range.

The debugging points to this line:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B7").Value = Target.Value
```

What am I doing wrong exactly?

Thanks!

Comment: [How to run a macro when certain cells change in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel)

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps me. Please advise.

Comment: It explains how to properly use `Worksheet_change`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose I want to mirror cell **`Sheet1.[A4]`** with cell **`Sheet2.[B7]`**, I'd use the following:

---

**Sheet1**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 'Sheet1 Module
    If Not Intersect(Target, [A4]) Is Nothing Then  'Update [B7] only when [A4] is updated
        MirrorCells Worksheets("Sheet2").[B7], Target
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**Sheet2**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 'Sheet2 Module
    If Not Intersect(Target, [B7]) Is Nothing Then  'Update [A4] only when [B7] is updated
        MirrorCells Worksheets("Sheet1").[A4], Target
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**Module1** (standard module)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MirrorCells(ByRef oldVal As Range, ByRef newVal As Range)
    If newVal.CountLarge = 1 Then   'Check that updated range is 1 cell (paste operations)
        If Not IsError(oldVal) And Not IsError(newVal) Then      'Ignore errors
            If oldVal <> newVal Then                'If oldVal needs to be updated
                Application.EnableEvents = False    'Stop all events
                oldVal.Value = newVal.Value         'Update it (triggers a new event)
                Application.EnableEvents = True     'Turn events back on
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

`Run-time error '9'` is generated because you don't have a sheet named exactly **`"Sheet2"`**

Check for extra spaces in the tab name, ex `"Sheet 2"`, or `"Sheet2 "`, or `" Sheet2"`

Comment: I made sure there weren't any spaces and that the name matched exactly, but it still didn't fix it. Your code; however, works great, so mine must have been off somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Another possible issue is if `Sheet2` is a **`Chart`**. (the `Sheet` Collection contains other types of sheets as well, but the typical Excel `Sheet` is in `Worksheets` Collection)